# How to signin multiple google accounts using google signin

Tags: ios, google-signin

In my iOS app, I need multiple google sign-in support. User can sign-in with more than one google accounts. Currently I'm using GoogleSignIn SDK for sign-in.

How can I achieve multiple google sign-in using GoogleSignIn SDK?